# Allocation of 3-dimensional array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, malloc, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

I tried to write a funtion to dynamically allocate a 3 dimensional array but my program crashes. Is Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int*** funcao(int a,int b,int c)
{
    int ***ppp=malloc(a*sizeof(int **));
    int i,j,k;

    for(i;i<a;i++)
    {
        ppp[i]=malloc(b*sizeof(int *));
    }
    for( i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<b;j++)
        {
            ppp[i][j]=malloc( c*sizeof(int));
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<b;j++)
        {
            for(k=0;k<c;k++)
            {
                ppp[i][j][k]=k*i*j;
            }
        }
    }

    return ppp;

    for( i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        for( j=0;j<b;j++)
        {
            free(ppp[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for( i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        free(ppp[i]);
    }

    free(ppp);
}

int main()
{
    int ***ppp=funcao(2,5,7);
}
```

Do you know where is the problem? Is it because I free the memory in the function after the return statement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `return` statement returns from a function immediately, code after an unconditional `return` statement is never executed. As for your problem, *where* does it crash? Does your simple program, as shown in the question crash? Have you tried running it in a debugger?

Comment: `for(i;i<a;i++){` --> `for(i=0;i<a;i++){`

Comment: This is *not* a 3D array, only an emulation of it. Don't do that if you mustn't, real 3D arrays are simple in modern C and much less error prone. Just do `int (*ppp)[b][c] = malloc(sizeof(int[a][b][c]));` and you have a 3D array. http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2014/09/08/dont-use-fake-matrices/

Answer (score 1):

You did not initialize variable `i`

```
int i,j,k;
```

So the loop has undefined behaviour

```
for(i;i<a;i++){
    ppp[i]=malloc(b*sizeof(int *));
}
```

Also it is not clear whar this part of the function does

```
for( i=0;i<a;i++){
    for( j=0;j<b;j++){
        free(ppp[i][j]);
    }}

for( i=0;i<a;i++){
    free(ppp[i]);
}

free(ppp);
}
```

after return statement

```
return ppp;
```

You should format your code appropriate way. Otherwise it is difficult to read it.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized variable `i` in this for loop `for(i;i<a;i++){`.

You correctly free the allocated memory, however you just did it at wrong place. After returning the pointer you should free it in the `main` function.

Check this fix code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int*** funcao(int a,int b,int c)
{
    int ***ppp = malloc( a * sizeof(int **) );
    int i, j, k;
    // Optimized your memory allocation code
    for(i=0; i < a; i++)
    {
        ppp[i] = malloc( b * sizeof(int *) );
        for(j=0; j < b; j++)
        {
            ppp[i][j] = malloc( c * sizeof(int) );
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j < b; j++)
        {
            for(k=0; k < c; k++)
            {
                ppp[i][j][k]=k+i+j;
                printf("%d\t",ppp[i][j][k]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return ppp;
}

int main()
{
    int ***ppp=funcao(2,5,7);
    int i, j, k;
    int a=2,b=5,c=7;
    //Free the memory
    for( i=0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for( j=0; j < b; j++)
        {
            free(ppp[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for( i=0; i < a; i++)
    {
        free(ppp[i]);
    }
    free(ppp);

    return 0;
}
```